# Where / How to install CentOS 7 for 32 bit system?

Tags: linux, centos

I have windows 7 with 32 bit system, and previously I used `CentOS-6.5-i386-minimal` to run centos on my virtual box, but now I would like to run CentOS 7 and it seems (if I am not mistaken) that there [are **No**](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/) links to download an `i386` image, as there are only `x86_64` which I am assuming is for the 64 bit systems.

## edit:

despite the answers I got here, I was able to install CentOS 7 and start working with no problem.

[image]

Comment: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=47473

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running 32-bit Windows 7 on a 64-bit processor, then VirtualBox can run a 64-bit guest with a few caveats:

> **[3.1.2. 64-bit guests](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)**
>
> VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit host operating systems, provided that the following conditions are met:
>
> 1. You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see Section 10.3, “Hardware vs. software virtualization”).
> 2. You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.
> 3. If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon explicit request.

To check whether your processor supports virtualization from Windows hosts, use the [Microsoft Hardware-Assisted Virtualization Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=592).

To check whether your processor supports virtualization from Linux hosts, run:

```
egrep '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

The above checks for either `vmx` or `svm` in `/etc/cpuinfo`.  If it finds either, it prints out all of the flags.  However, if it doesn't find them, it will not print anything.  The latter means you do not have hardware virtualization.

Comment: Hmm, I guess this answer my question. From the description I can understand, that if atleast I have visualization support (which I have, since I have been using CentOS 6.5 on a virtualbox) then I should be able to run 64bit. right?

Comment: Only if you were running the 64-bit version of CentOS6.5.  Check your processor - I've added to my answer.

Comment: thanks, but are you sure that command is correct? I run it, and I get nothing. No response at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, that means you do not have hardware virtualization - I've edited my answer.

Comment: Well, actually I managed to install CentOS 7. Which I am working on right now. So, there must be something wrong with your answer, or maybe some bug or something.

Comment: @Contax - Your image is a little difficult to see, but as far as I can tell, you have an Intel Core i3 processor.  I believe that these do support hardware virtualization (VT-x) which is why you can run a 64-bit guest OS (CentOS 7) on a 32-bit host OS (Windows 7) on a 64-bit processor (Intel Core i3). This confirms to Virtual Box's list in my original answer.

Comment: [full size image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qJN0V.jpg) so i suppose that we can stop saying 32 bit and start saying that core i3 is the real threshold

Comment: @Contax - The Intel website for [your processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/50178/Intel-Core-i3-380M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_53-GHz) states that it supports VT-x, so you are running a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualisation support.

Answer (score 4):

From the [CentOS wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS):

> CentOS aims to be 100% binary compatible with its upstream source, Red Hat
>   Enterprise Linux (RHEL)

From the [Red Hat website](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/509373):

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 will only provide 64-bit ISO's, thus allowing only
>   a 64-bit operating environment. However, 32-bit is supported in the following
>   ways:
>
> - RHEL 7 will continue to provide selected libraries in both 32-bit and
>     64-bit, allowing 32-bit applications to run in the 64-bit RHEL 7 OS
>     environment. This functionality also exists for RHEL 5 & 6 as documented in
>     the knowledge article: [How to install 32-bit packages on a 64-bit
>     system](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/329913)
> - RHEL 7 will continue to support the multilib toolchain, allowing
>     applications to be compiled for both 32-bit and 64-bit.
> - RHEL 7 can host, using KVM virtualization technology, both 32-bit and
>     64-bit virtual guest instances of RHEL 5 and RHEL 6
>
> While RHEL 7 will not natively support 32-bit hardware, certified hardware
>   can be searched for in the [certified hardware database](https://hardware.redhat.com/).

Comment: I am struggling to find a concrete and tangible answer in the second paragraph, aside from the fact that their "solution" takes me the a login page. I guess, only fedora can provide CentOS 7 for 32 bit systems.

Comment: Their solution is for 32-bit applications to run on the 64-bit operating environment. I do not know any details about an apparent community supported 32 bit edition being created.

Comment: Fedora has nothing to do with CentOS, they're totally different distros.

Comment: @slm I know that. I was just assuming that maybe CentOS does not have that option. (running a 64bit image on a 32bit distro)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is another distribution based on RHEL called Springdale and it has both 64-bit and 32-bit versions: http://springdale.math.ias.edu/

Take it with a grain of salt though, I haven't tried it and I don't know what are the differences between this and CentOS (if there are any).

Comment: Actually as stated already later in the comment, it was possible for me to install CentOs7 on 32bit.

Comment: sadly, Springdale still ships systemd, so it's out as a successor in my shop; but shipping a 32-bit version is nice.

I think there were some 32-bit respins of centos7, too.